# How to write to ofstream accessed through map iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map of `ofstream`. I'm going through a packet of messages and want to write each message pertaining to a specific symbol to its respective file, in essence dividing the packet file into smaller ones. It writes to the file when I `<<` to the `ofstream`. However when I try to `<<` to the `ofstream` accessed via the map iterator it crashes even though it compiles fine.

The reason I'm using a map is to ensure that the packet header is not writen more than once for a given symbol.

```
void write_packet_to_symbol_file(packet p)
{

  string path = "E:\\20170131\\";
  map<string,ofstream&> outs;
  for (message m : p.messages) {
    map<string,ofstream&>::iterator it = outs.find(m.symbol.name);
    if (it == outs.end()) { 
        string full_path = path + m.symbol.name + ".CAP";
        ofstream of;
        of.open(full_path, ios_base::app); 
        // write packet header since first message for that symbol
        of << p.get_header();
        outs.emplace(m.symbol.name,of);
    }

    map<string,ofstream&>::iterator it2 = outs.find(m.symbol.name);
    if (it2 != outs.end())
      it2->second << m.get_message_content();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the name isn't found, you open a new stream and add it to the map. But you never assign `it` to point to it.

Comment: You're doing two things wrong: you're assuming that just because the program compiles, it is correct. That's obviously not true. Secondly, stream objects are not copyable, so you cannot construct and open a stream objects, and copy them into the map afterwards. They are movable, but you need to move the stream object properly, for this to work.

Comment: After inserting incorrectly a new node into the map, the iterator `it` which you are going to deference is still equal to outs.end().

Comment: @Barmar i did a new iterator and it's not crashing anymore. However it doesn't wrote the message content to the file.

Comment: @Sam Varsharvchik please elaborate on moving stream object properly

Comment: @felix why is my way of inserting ofstream into the map incorrect?

Comment: 400 characters in a stackoverflow.com comment is, unfortunately, not enough to fully and completely explain move semantics in C++11. I'll refer you to your C++ book, which should fully explain the subject matter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, you don't need move semantics if you get rid of the temporary stream object and instead create it directly within the map using operator[]. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ofstream instance is a local variable of the if-statement and will be closed and discarded when the if-statement terminates. You almost never want to use collections of references like your map, instead you should create a map of strings to ofstream pointers (preferably to smart pointers), create the ofstreams dynamically, and scrap all the code you have already written.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth if it will be discard at the end of the if block how does a pointer persist it?

Comment: @Beh A pointer doesn't persist it; creating it with `new` will persist it. Also, you could use move semantics, but not with a map of references.

Comment: Neither pointers nor move semantics are required to make this work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already explained, you are creating only a temporary ofstream object inside the if block. This object gets destroyed when the if block ends so the reference stored in the map will be invalid then.

You want a `map<string,ofstream>` because the map should actually store the stream object, not just a reference to it.

Now we have the problem, how to put the temporary stream into the map? Copying a stream object is not possible, because streams have no copy constructors nor assignment operators.

It turns out the temporary object is not required, because you can create the stream object directly inside the map using operator[].

So you don't even need pointers or move semantics as some users suggested!

```
void write_packet_to_symbol_file(packet p)
{

  string path = "E:\\20170131\\";
  map<string,ofstream> outs;
  for (message m : p.messages) {
    map<string,ofstream>::iterator it = outs.find(m.symbol.name);
    if (it == outs.end()) {
        // Create stream object in the map and get reference 'of' to it
        ofstream& of = outs[ m.symbol.name ];

        string full_path = path + m.symbol.name + ".CAP";
        of.open(full_path, ios_base::app); 
        // write packet header since first message for that symbol
        of << p.get_header();

        // No need to insert 'of' into 'outs', because it is already in there! 
    }

    map<string,ofstream>::iterator it2 = outs.find(m.symbol.name);
    if (it2 != outs.end())
      it2->second << m.get_message_content();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a `map` from string to **ofstream reference**. I am not sure how that compiles but that is definitely a bug since the referenced objects get destructed.

I think you should use `map<string,ofstream>`
Then you should `.insert()` `.emplace()` into the map and on the returned iterator you should call `it->second.open()`.

This might be a little tricky since the `ifstream` is not copyable but is movable so

```
map.insert(make_pair(some_key, ifstream(...))); //this will work, calls move

ifstream x;
map.insert(make_pair(some_key, x)); //this will NOT work, calls copy

map.insert(make_pair(some_key, std::move(x))); // should work
```

Similar is for `emplace`, that skips the `make_pair` call.

Comment: It gets compiled because it is syntactically correct. Anything else the compiler does for you, like warnings, is gravy. One cannot assume the logic is correct from correct grammar. I cite example politicians as an example.